# How can I increase the speed and frequency of a spawn?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using the [official Unity tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNTph6E2Fvg) for the Space Shooter game, and I'm at the part where the ability to spawn a set amount of hazards in a wave at a certain delay is introduced.

I want to make it so that at the end of a certain level, the speed of the hazards, and the amount of hazards both increase. I'm pretty sure that can be handled in the game controller, but I don't know the commands I would be needing to use to make that happen. This is the existing code:

```
public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject hazard;
    public Vector3 spawnValues;
    public int hazardCount;
    public float spawnWait;
    public float startWait;
    public float waveWait;

    void Start ()
    {
        StartCoroutine (SpawnWaves());
    }    

    IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()   
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);
        while (true) 
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++) 
            {
                Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (Random.Range (-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
                Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
                Instantiate (hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait); 
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        }
    }
}
```

What commands would I need to use to increase the amount of hazards that spawn at the end of each round? And likewise, how could I change the Hazard's script so that it will increase in speed by a certain factor at the end of each round? Is there a way I can reference the hazard's script in this script, by any chance?

Comment: What have you tried? For example, increasing the value of `hazardCount` and decreasing the value of `waveWait` would be a pretty good start.

Answer (score 1):

`hazardCount` is the number of hazards spawned each round.
`spawnWait` is the delay between spawning of each Hazard in one Wave.
`waveWait` is the length of each Wave.

You can add your own variable, `WaveCounter` that you can increase each Wave. And another variable to control how much you want the `spawnWait` to decrease each new Wave.

```
int WaveCounter = 0;
int HazardCountIncrease = 1;
float SpawnSpeedIncrease = 0.1f;

IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()   
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);
    while (true) 
    {
        hazardCount += (WaveCounter * HazardCountIncrease);
        for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++) 
        {
            Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3 (Random.Range (-spawnValues.x, spawnValues.x), spawnValues.y, spawnValues.z);
            Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            Instantiate (hazard, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait - (WaveCounter * SpawnSpeedIncrease)); 
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waveWait);
        WaveCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is something like `if(WaveCounter%3==0) hazardCount++;`. Where the hazard count would increase every three levels.